# How to prevent android os to delete an activity from stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

is it possible.

If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely restarted and restored to its previous state.

above from this [link](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/13/android-activity-life-cycle/)..

I want to ask android os not to delete a particular activity which is in stack.. is it possible

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not possible under extreme circumstances system will kill activities

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Android can and will terminate your process as it sees fit, including when the user asks to terminate your process (e.g., swiping your app off of the recent-tasks list). You need to write your app such that you can pick up where the user left off, by storing relevant data somewhere (files, databases, preferences, etc.).

Comment: Writing an app in such a way is near impossible when your entire content is loaded from the web What I have most about android is the way to pass data inside your app

Comment: @IllegalArgument: "Writing an app in such a way is near impossible when your entire content is loaded from the web" -- either save the "content" to files, or reload it from the "web". This is what a Web browser does, and it is not "near impossible" to write a Web browser. In fact, this is what most Internet-connected applications do.

Comment: I did the latter reloading and caching only images in memory I just wish there was an easy way